# Backbone Marionette collection view on route change render view with data doesn't work

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Backbone Marionette.CollectionView it's rendering data from server when call in MyApp.addInitiliazer method but not rendering(not showing on the html) when call in Marionette.AppRouter why it is not rendering i am cofused is it a bug?

**Updated:**
When i navigate to /app#other then back to /app#samples collection view does not showing data. if you better apporache for this app please tell me i be glad.

**App.js**

```
var MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application(); 
MyApp.addRegions({

    // Layout regions
    menu: '#menu',
    headermenu: '.top-menu',
    content: '#views',

    // Sub pages
    innermenu: '#innermenu',
    samples: '#sample-container' 
});

MyApp.vent.on("routing:started", function () {
    if (!Backbone.History.started) {
        Backbone.history.start({ appRoot: '/app#' });
    }
});
```

**SampleAppList.js**

```
MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList = {};

MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.Sample = Backbone.Model.extend({
    id: null,
    name: '',
    picture: '/assets/img/default-sample.jpg'
});

MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.SampleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.Sample,
    url: '/api/samples'
});

MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.SampleItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#sample-view",
    tagName: 'li'
});

MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.SampleCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.SampleItemView,
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'sample-list',
});
```

**SampleApp.js**

```
MyApp.SampleApp = {};

MyApp.SampleApp.IndexView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#sample-layout'
});

MyApp.SampleApp.IndexInnerMenuView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#sample-view-inner-menu',
});

MyApp.SampleApp.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        "samples": "LoadPage"
    }
});

MyApp.SampleApp.LoadPage = function () {

    //utils.setDocumentTitle('samples');

    var index = new MyApp.SampleApp.IndexView();
    MyApp.content.show(index);

    var inner = new MyApp.SampleApp.IndexInnerMenuView();
    MyApp.innermenu.show(inner);

    var sCollection = new MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.SampleCollection();
    sCollection.fetch();

    var cv = new MyApp.SampleApp.SampleList.SampleCollectionView({ collection: sCollection });
    MyApp.samples.show(cv);

    console.log('Route: Samples');
};

MyApp.addInitializer(function () {
    var router = new MyApp.SampleApp.Router({
        controller: MyApp.SampleApp
    });
    MyApp.SampleApp.LoadPage();
    MyApp.vent.trigger("routing:started");
});
```

**OtherApp.js**

```
MyApp.OtherApp = {};

MyApp.OtherApp.IndexView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#other-layout'
});

MyApp.OtherApp.IndexInnerMenuView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#other-view-inner-menu',
});

MyApp.OtherApp.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        "other": "LoadOtherPage"
    }
});

MyApp.OtherApp.LoadOtherPage = function () {
    var index = new MyApp.OtherApp.IndexView();
    MyApp.content.show(index);

    var innermenu = new MyApp.OtherApp.IndexInnerMenuView();
    MyApp.innermenu.show(innermenu); 
};

MyApp.addInitializer(function () {
    MyApp.OtherApp.Router = new MyApp.OtherApp.Router({
        controller: MyApp.OtherApp
    });
    MyApp.vent.trigger("routing:started");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly this looks odd:

```
MyApp.SampleApp.Router = new MyApp.SampleApp.Router({
    controller: MyApp.SampleApp
});
```

you shouldn't rewrite the MyApp.SampleApp.Router class but instantiate a new object, like:

```
var router = new MyApp.SampleApp.Router({
    controller: MyApp.SampleApp
});
```

Another thing that looks strange is the way you define the LoadPage function. Is it a member of a controlle object? You should define a controller, like:

```
     var Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        loadPage: function() { .... }
     })
```

and in the MyApp.addInitializer instantiate it with:

```
var controller = new Controller();
```

I guess there is something wrong with objects and scope. Please check you have access to them and not having undefined instead.

If you need more help, having the complete code would he

Comment: I tryed  "var router" given same result. I am updating my post wit all code.

Comment: I think you are confusing classes with objects. Read the docs: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.3.2/marionette.controller.html

Comment: Usually you declare classes and instantiate with new keyword.